# Capital gains for agricultural land converted to non-agricultural land for the purpose of sale?

Tags: taxes, india, real-estate, capital-gain, capital-gains-tax

I held some agricultural land in Gujarat state for 14 years, and sold it on 20th August. As per the law in Gujarat, a non-farmer cannot hold agricultural land, so the land status was changed to non-agricultural status 3 months back for the purpose of sale.

Now will I be able to avail long term capital gains benefit or is it business income?

Comment: Country? Location is always needed to answer tax questions

Answer (score 1):

Gains Agricultural land is non-taxable. However if the status of the land is changed, it would be Capital Gains, there is no business income here unless the land was bought on Companys name.

Please consult a CA, there would be benefit of indexation as well as arriving at the fair price.